# Code restricted to pure Javascript; need Jquery translation

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I'm writing a website for a good friend of mine.  I know pure JavaScript but jQuery just looks like a jumbled mess to me.  I haven't taken the time to learn it.  Still, I don't mind using a function when I find it on the internet.  That's what happened with this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/ykbgT/2/).  I was so happy when I found it and was using it to switch pages on a manga reader I had constructed.

The code I wish to alter is below in a working example (should the jsFiddle die and someone want this awesome code by jsFiddle user jtbowden).

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(window).load(function(){
$('.box').click(function() {

$(this).animate({
    left: '-50%'
}, 500, function() {
    $(this).css('left', '150%');
    $(this).appendTo('#container');
});

$(this).next().animate({
    left: '50%'
}, 500);
});
})

</script>

<style type="text/css">
body {
padding: 0px;    
}

#container {
position: absolute;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 310px;
overflow: hidden; 
background-color:black; 
}

.box {
position: absolute;
width: 23%;
height: 300px;
line-height: 300px;
font-size: 50px;
text-align: center;
border: 2px solid black;
left: 150%;
top: 5px;
margin-left: -25%;
}

img.cover {
position:absolute;
display:block;
margin-left:5%;
margin-right:auto;
top:5%;
height:90%
}

img.cover:hover {
position:absolute;
display:block;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
top:0%;
height:100%
}

#box1 {
background-color: green;
left: 30%;
}

#box2 {
background-color: yellow;
}

#box3 {
background-color: red;
}

#box4 {
background-color: orange;
}

#box5 {
background-color: blue;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="box1" class="box"></div>
<div id="box2" class="box">Div #2</div>
<div id="box3" class="box">Div #3</div>
<div id="box4" class="box">Div #4</div>
<div id="box5" class="box">Div #5</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

However, my friend disliked the code because he, like me, cannot read it.  It's his website and he's paying me well enough so he's the boss.  He's asked that I rewrite this code from jQuery to pure JavaScript so he can understand it, which will allow him to make his own changes in the future should he need to or simply feel like it.  The thing is, I don't know how.  I simply found this code which did what I wanted, added it to the site, and edited the CSS to accommodate what I needed.  I have no clue how this code works, nor what I need to do to make it pure JavaScript.

I told him that but he isn't backing down.  I'm been restricted to pure JavaScript, HTML5 and CSS3 for the website.  He's not going to pay me the rest of the money until it's been put into pure JavaScript and rent is coming up due.  So, I was kind of hoping someone out there would help me reinvent the wheel and translate the jQuery code in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/ykbgT/2/) to pure JavaScript.

At the very least, can you please walk me through the code and the bits in the jQuery library and tell me exactly what this is doing, other than shifting the left property?  How is it showing the animation (I take it, this is the .animate part)?  I thought browsers skipped frames in the middle?

Any help would be appreciated by me, my friend, and (eventually) my landlord.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:  I rewrote this using CSS animation:

```
    <html>
    <head>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function divSwitch(num) {
    var currentBox=document.getElementById("box"+num);
    if (num>=5) {
    num=0;
    }
    var nextBox=document.getElementById("box"+(num+1));

    var checkedButton = getCheckedRadio(document.forms.setOption.elements.aniOption);
    if (checkedButton) {
    switch(checkedButton.value) {
    case "R":
    currentBox.className="outFromRtL";
    nextBox.className="inFromRtL";
    break;

    case "L":
    currentBox.className="outFromLtR";
    nextBox.className="inFromLtR";
    break;  

    case "N":
    if (currentBox.className!="box") {
    for (var q=1; q<=5; q++) {
    var setBoxBack=document.getElementById("box"+q);
    setBoxBack.className="box";
    }
    }
    currentBox.style.left='-50%';
    nextBox.style.left='50%';
    break;

    default:
    alert("Well... That's not supposed to happen!  How did you break it!?");
    break;
    }
    }
    }

    function getCheckedRadio(radio_group) {
        for (var i = 0; i < radio_group.length; i++) {
            var button = radio_group[i];
            if (button.checked) {
                return button;
            }
        }
        return undefined;
    }
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        body {
        padding: 0px;    
    }

    #container {
        position: absolute;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 310px;
        overflow: hidden; 
    background-color:black; 
    }

    .box {
        position: absolute;
        width: 23%;
        height: 300px;
        line-height: 300px;
        font-size: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        border: 2px solid black;
        left: 150%;
        top: 5px;
    }

    .inFromRtL {
        position: absolute;
        width: 23%;
        height: 300px;
        line-height: 300px;
        font-size: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        border: 2px solid black;
        left: 50%;
        top: 5px;

    -moz-animation-duration: 850ms;
    -moz-animation-name: rightSlideIn;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }

    @-moz-keyframes rightSlideIn {
          from {
            left:150%;
          }
          to {
            left:50%;
          }
    }

    .outFromRtL {
        position: absolute;
        width: 23%;
        height: 300px;
        line-height: 300px;
        font-size: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        border: 2px solid black;
        left: -50%;
        top: 5px;

    -moz-animation-duration: 850ms;
    -moz-animation-name: rightSlideOut;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }

    @-moz-keyframes rightSlideOut {
          from {
            left:50%;
          }
          to {
            left:-150%;
          }
    }

    .inFromLtR {
        position: absolute;
        width: 23%;
        height: 300px;
        line-height: 300px;
        font-size: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        border: 2px solid black;
        left: 50%;
        top: 5px;

    -moz-animation-duration: 850ms;
    -moz-animation-name: leftSlideIn;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }

    @-moz-keyframes leftSlideIn {
          from {
            left:-150%;
          }
          to {
            left:50%;
          }
    }

    .outFromLtR {
        position: absolute;
        width: 23%;
        height: 300px;
        line-height: 300px;
        font-size: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        border: 2px solid black;
        left: 150%;
        top: 5px;

    -moz-animation-duration: 850ms;
    -moz-animation-name: leftSlideOut;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }

    @-moz-keyframes leftSlideOut {
          from {
            left:50%;
          }
          to {
            left:150%;
          }
    }

    #box1 {
        background-color: green;
        left: 50%;
    }

    #box2 {
        background-color: yellow;
    }

    #box3 {
        background-color: red;
    }

    #box4 {
        background-color: orange;
    }

    #box5 {
        background-color: blue;
    }
      </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="container">
    <div id="box1" class="box" onclick="divSwitch(1);">Div #1</div>
    <div id="box2" class="box" onclick="divSwitch(2);">Div #2</div>
    <div id="box3" class="box" onclick="divSwitch(3);">Div #3</div>
    <div id="box4" class="box" onclick="divSwitch(4);">Div #4</div>
    <div id="box5" class="box" onclick="divSwitch(5);">Div #5</div>
    </div>
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <div id="animationOptions">
    <form id="setOption">
    <input type="radio" name="aniOption" id="L" value="L" checked="true">Left to Right
    <input type="radio" name="aniOption" id="R" value="R">Right to Left
    <input type="radio" name="aniOption" id="N" value="N">None
    </form>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Yeah, it is a bit more code but it's still just 5kb and I wont need the 75kb jQuery file.

Comment: The event binding and DOM manipulations can be relatively easily translated, but you're going to have a lot of problems trying to animate elements across all browsers in native JavaScript. These are the kind of problems you don't want to worry about and why you'd use a library such as jQuery.

Comment: Personally I think it'll become more complex after changed to pure javascript because it involves animations which is a big part of jQuery. Besides, jQuery makes things easier and make code much shorter .

Comment: If you're depending on HTML5/CSS3 already, you can use CSS transitions and these will animate the elements when you set their style properties. Though, you will most likely lose readability than gain as @Licson commented.

Comment: I am not worried about all browsers, only Firefox.  It has to work on his computer and that's what he uses.  Let him alter it for the others if he wants.

Comment: jQuery is a javascript library that was created to make doing this stuff easier. While it's not impossible to write it in javascript, it's definitely going to be much harder to understand. Why don't you both invest the time in trying to understand jQuery. Here you go: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp

Comment: Like Mattias said, task is pretty simple, but animation. [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/zsgsQ/2/) a snippet for a simple animation with pure JS. It's not exactly what you need (created for another answer), but you can develope it further...

Comment: I agree with all the comments, what's the point of rewriting jQuery if the code is already written for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There two ways to approach this, first use [jsapi.info](http://jsapi.info/jquery/1.8.0/) it will show you the source of  specific methods and functions, the other way is just to look at and study the [source code](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.js), that's what I do when good documentation is not available for some module or some library, and as Paul Irish calls it "documentation for professionals" and since you know pure JavaScript it should be easy for you to read. hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Its not possible to make this any simpler than it is. If you unwind the jQuery, you will find the code behind it to be very complicated relative to what you are looking at now. It would just be easier to look at jquery.com documentation in what the methods are doing. I'll comment for you.

```
// when the window is loaded, do the code within
$(window).load(function() {
  // now i can assign events since the dom is loaded
  // but you could use $(document).ready instead

  // when any class with "box" is clicked, do the code within
  // this is binding a click event to all elements having a "box" class
  $('.box').click(function() {

    // animate the currently clicked "box" element
    $(this).animate({
      // move it left 50% and take 500 milliseconds to do it
      left: '-50%' 
    }, 500, function() {
      // the code here is called once the animation has completed
      // set the style to left 150%
      $(this).css('left', '150%');
      // put the box inside the element with id=container
      $(this).appendTo('#container');
    });

    // animate the element just next to the box element 
    // moving it left 50% taking 500 milliseconds to do it.
    $(this).next().animate({ left: '50%' }, 500);

  });

});
```

Now imagine you had to write the animation code using setInterval and easing functions not to mention the cross-browser events. Make this code 10 x more lengthy and complicated and you will probably be doing something similar.

Comment: Can you rewrite this code into pure JavaScript without the animation?  Just switch the boxes around?

Comment: The point is to learn from what people are telling you, not have it written for you. If you are unable to grep the jQuery code yourself, you have to ask yourself if you should be doing this at all.